# List<byte> behaves differently to ArrayBufferWriter<byte>?

Tags: c#, networking

Decided to refactory `List<byte>` to a `ArrayBufferWriter<byte>` but getting different outputs when "compiling" the builder. It seems the list works but ArrayBufferWriter doesn't write it correctly? I've tried `GetMemory()` and `GetStream()`

I call `WriteShort` in the constructor, and then call `WriteString` twice passing `""` both times. This happens when only having `ArrayBufferWriter<byte>` in the class also.

I just put both in there to show without more code than required.

Code:

```
public class ServerPacketBuilder
{
    private readonly ArrayBufferWriter<byte> _packet;
    private readonly List<byte> _packetList;

    protected ServerPacketBuilder(short packetId)
    {
        _packet = new ArrayBufferWriter<byte>();
        _packetList = new List<byte>();

        WriteShort(packetId);
    }

    protected void WriteString(string data)
    {
        WriteShort((short) data.Length);
        WriteBytes(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data));
    }

    private void WriteBytes(byte[] data)
    {
        _packet.Write(data);
        _packetList.AddRange(data);
    }

    private void WriteShort(short length)
    {
        _packet.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(length));
        _packetList.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(length));
    }

    public byte[] GetBytes()
    {
        var finalBytes = new List<byte>();

        Console.WriteLine("1: " + Encoding.Default.GetString(_packetList.ToArray()));
        Console.WriteLine("2: " + Encoding.Default.GetString(_packet.GetSpan().ToArray()));

        finalBytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(_packetList.Count()));
        finalBytes.Reverse();
        finalBytes.AddRange(_packetList);

        return finalBytes.ToArray();
    }
}
```

These output different values

```
Console.WriteLine("1: " + Encoding.Default.GetString(_packetList.ToArray()));
Console.WriteLine("2: " + Encoding.Default.GetString(_packet.GetSpan().ToArray()));
```

The first one will output the correct value, and the second one will output an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

`_packet.GetSpan()` returns a span to write to, which will not contain any data already written. You probably want `_packet.WrittenSpan` instead.